How to set USB read write permission so any user can read/write/execute on it?
I don't understand. I was able to set read/write/execute permission using terminal for any USB driver I connected to my Raspberry Pi, but now I simply can't no matter what command I execute.
sudo chmod 777 "USB mountpoint"

sudo chwon -R root:root "USB mountpoint"

I simply want to be able to create file or make changes to existing files in the USB, but this baffles me.
How do you change USB permission? So, you can read/write/execute files from USB drive.

your question is not about the Raspberry Pi  ... it is a question about the Linux file system

The permissions you are interested in are purely filesystem oriented and are distinct from permissions to do with devices, ie., they work the same way regardless of whether they are on a USB stick or the SD card.  I mention this to save you confusion.  This methodology is one linux inherited from UNIX and it is subtly different from MS Windows systems where drive paths (eg. "C:/") are used, conflating the filesystem with the device it is on.
This may be why you assume:
sudo chmod 777 "USB mountpoint"

Sets the permissions for everything on the USB device.  It does not.  The mountpoint is just a directory, and that sets the permissions only for that directory -- not anything below/inside it.  To do that you need to use -R switch, as you do with chown.
If the filesystem on the stick is FAT (and ostensibly, NTFS), you can use this instead when you mount:
mount -o umask=000 ....

That can be used in /etc/fstab as well.  Notice the value is the inverse of the "777" when setting a permission (because it is a mask).
You probably should use 666 and not 777 though. The "1" just adds execute permission and most files are actually not executable; setting them so may create problesms.
